# Creating a dynamic array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct

I need to create an array of structs but I have to read the array size from a file. My problem is that I might be using the pointers all wrong. I can't use global variables. Here's the code I made :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct driver
{
       int *amount;
       int ADT1[9];
       int ADO1[9];
};

struct driver totaldrivers[*amount];
```

The errors(2) I get are "amount undeclared here(not in a function)" and "storage size of 'totaldrivers' isn't known". I tried giving the *amount a value directly but no luck and even so the amount must be taken by the file the user has created and the number is the first line. And that's where I have my issue. The (.txt)file format is:

4(amount of entries)
123456789 , 978675645 (ADT1,ADO1)
.
.
.
I am sure I've made rookie mistakes so forgive me if the question is silly.

Comment: Should the array of structs be global ?

Comment: `amount` is not a global variable, you need an initialized `driver` structure instance to access it.

Comment: I think the point is to read the first line and use that to size your array, not put it inside your struct.

Comment: if 'amount' is count of number of entries then dont put in the struct

Comment: no the array should not be global.

Comment: Also, you don't need one `int` per digit. Instead a single `unsigned int` will be enough.

Comment: Then you can do as pointed out by others in the comments above.

Comment: There are no silly questions… except the ones about dynamically allocating arrays. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming the contents of your structure should be as follows (I've removed `int *amount`):

```
struct driver
{
    int ADT1[9];
    int ADO1[9];
};
```

To create a dynamic 1D array of these structures, first create a pointer to a 1D array of `driver`:

```
struct driver *pDriver;
```

Next, allocate memory for the number of elements you need in the array.  This should be known (`N`):

```
pDriver = malloc(N * sizeof(*pDriver));
```

If you want to keep a record of the number of elements, you should do something like this:

```
struct driver
{
    int ADT1[9];
    int ADO1[9];
};

struct driverArray
{
    int numDrivers;
    struct driver *pDriver;
};

struct driverArray driverArr;

driverArr.numDrivers = N;
driverArr.pDriver = malloc(driverArr.numDrivers * sizeof(*driverArr.pDriver));
```

Comment: this one seems like it works. will update soon when i finish the rest of the code.

Comment: code works like a charm but i have another issue. I got informed that i need to use functions and not just one main. how do i pass this array in the function?

Comment: despite this answer being correct I couldn't figure out how to pass the arrays in the function. asking my mates i got a different way that worked better for me. thanks anyway!

Comment: Ask another question if you need more help. Godd luck.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than

```
struct driver totaldrivers[*amount];
```

Set up a pointer to refer to it, then allocate the array from the heap when you know the size you'll need.

```
struct driver totaldrivers[];
int amount=7; /* for example */
totaldrivers=malloc(sizeof(struct driver)*amount);
/* Apology for the typo; I wrote "driver=" the first time. Good catch! */
```

You also probably don't want that "int *amount" inside the struct.

Comment: This is not correct.  You must create memory for the variable, `totaldrivers`, not the type, `driver`.

Comment: Good catch. Pure finger-check and sloppy proofreading. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct driver totaldrivers[*amount];
```

here, you use **array** (first method):

`* amount` is the size the array of driver struct. this is a wrong way to define size of array !!
there is many way to define the size of array some of them:

1) preprocessor using define directive:  `#define size 12`

2) global variable :  int size  12

you can also use **pointer** (second method):

```
struct driver *totaldrivers;

totaldrivers= malloc(nb * sizeof(*totaldrivers)); // nb : number of elements
```

you should not complicated your code take it easy !

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is to use the dynamic stack allocation facility introduced in C99.  Just make sure your compiler is C99 compilant.

As the others have said, dispense with amount.

```
struct driver
{
    int ADT1[9];
    int ADO1[9];
};
```

Introduce a function to do whatever you want.  Allocate the array here

```
void RunWith(int amount)
{
    struct driver totaldrivers[amount];

    ... 
}
```

In the caller, pass in the amount

```
int main ()
{
    RunWith(25);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

There is no need to malloc or free.